# Is it bad practice to use string interpolation to build a sql query also when using the escape function?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

Someone said that using string interpolation is bad practice also when using the escape function:

```
const db = require('./config);
...
`SELECT * from Users where username=${db.escape(username)}`
```

but is it really bad practice? I mean I am still escaping the variable or is something else wrong with the query above? I am really unsure right now.

Comment: Yes.  This is really a bad practice and subjects your code both to unintentional and hard-to-debug errors and to SQL injection.  There is also a perfectly safe and easy to use work-around:  parameters.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for your answer! I will stop using string interpolation for building queries from now on!

Comment: Consider using `knex` which is a sql query-builder

Comment: @felixmosh Thank you for the reference, I will look it up!